# Application Bar for Windows Phone App is not showing in Emulator

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, application-bar

I am trying to create an Application Bar for my Windows Phone Silverlight app. I've checked this code several times. I see no error. Even I checked on MSDN's website. But when I'm running this on Emulator, the Application Bar is not showing.

What's wrong with my code?

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Default"  Opacity="1.0" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/ApplicationBar/next.png" Text="Next" Click="appBar_next"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Here's the full XAML Code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Share_Bills.getPersonNum"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="SHARE BILLS" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="step 1" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="How many persons are you?" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="53" Width="436"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="personNum" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Margin="0,25,0,0" InputScope="Number"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNext1" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="326,97,0,0" Width="130" Click="btnNext1_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtError" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,102,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311" Height="134"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Default"  Opacity="1.0" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/ApplicationBar/next.png" Text="Next" Click="appBar_next"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar></phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Where is the ApplicationBar XAML in your project?

Comment: Are sure that you have it within your `XAML` page? other than that your code seems to be ok. Just try changing the Mode and remove the opacity property.

Comment: I tried changing the mode and opacity but it doesn't work!

Comment: Could you add the rest of your xaml code for the page, so that we can see the if there may be an issue there?

Comment: @ShahriarSirajSnigdho Hey, Where is the Close tag for `phone:PhoneApplicationPage` in your full XAML code. I believe the visual studio gives error `The XML tag "phone:PhoneApplicationPage" is not closed.` After adding closing tagline it is working fine me(with applciationbar). if it is didn't helps you please create sample app & upload it.

Comment: Nope bro! I've phone:PhoneApplicationPage close tag. But still not working

Comment: In that case that is weird. Would you please upload your sample project to dropbox & give us link. I will help you :)

Comment: Ok here's the link: http://1drv.ms/1syJzfH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Compiled your project it is working fine with ApplicationBar. Initially you set your Project Entry Point to `MainPage.xaml`, But you mentioned your problem with `getPersonNum.xaml` page in Code. I ran the `getPersonNum.xaml`.

Here is the screenshot of my Emulator :

[image]

Hope this helps.